# Question viewed 8 times, and 8 upvotes? possible?

Tags: discussion, views

[image]

Is it even possible? I mean 1 view is default OP's view. How is it possible then?

Link :[@Named providers with same return types end up giving java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581183/named-providers-with-same-return-types-end-up-giving-java-lang-illegalargumente)

Comment: The "viewed" counter isn't exactly accurate.

Comment: I understand it's not accurate. Does it make it a reason for down-voting?

Comment: In the android tag everything gets upvoted, no matter what so I'm less surprised as you are....

Comment: @rene not really.The question is about the calculation.Cause I wasn't knowing about the inconsistency about the counter.

Comment: When I view the question now it sits at 10 votes for 21 views. The view count is cached.

Comment: It's certainly possible.. the mismatch (I think) usually occurs with really bad questions, whereas if a question is upvoted so much with so little views, it normally seems suspicious and may need to be looked into for sock puppet voting. Cross site dup of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79529/an-answer-has-more-votes-than-views Caching, like others said.

Comment: It could also have been a race condition.